# What parts of a bootable ISO are required and what to put in them

Tags: iso, bootable

So I wanted to make a bootable USB of my personal Linux From Scratch. But I cannot find any guide on how to do this. So what files are absolutely required and what parts are optional, I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is a bootable USB, then the first optional thing is calling it an *ISO* in the first place.

Normally, a disk image file with the `.iso` suffix indicates that the image file uses an ISO-9660 (or possibly UDF) filesystem, and is intended to be burned onto optical media (CD, DVD or Blu-Ray).

Disk images using any other formats should technically be called something else; `.bin`, `.img` or `.dmg` are common suffixes for those.

When booting from USB, the USB disk is essentially treated the same as a hard disk, so to make a USB media bootable, you should do exactly the same things you would do to a hard disk to make it bootable.

The first necessary thing is to satisfy the boot requirements of the expected system firmware, so that your USB media will be recognizable as bootable.

---

On legacy BIOS systems, this means the last two bytes of the first 512-byte block (= block #0) should be 0x55 0xAA, identifying it as a valid Master Boot Record, or MBR for short. A further 64 bytes is normally occupied by a MBR partition table (but a custom bootloader could perhaps ignore that requirement). The remaining 446 bytes will contain a 16-bit x86 machine code program that will be loaded and executed by the firmware. When we're talking about booting Linux, that 446 bytes will be the very first part of a *bootloader*.

446 bytes of machine code is just barely enough to load in other parts of the bootloader, so any modern bootloader will occupy more than just the 446 bytes within the MBR. On a USB media prepared for BIOS-style booting, you could use the `i386-pc` version of GRUB, SYSLINUX, old LILO, or any other bootloader you find appropriate for your purposes. Everything after that depends on which bootloader you'll choose to use.

---

On modern 64-bit x86 systems booting in UEFI style, the requirements for booting from removable media are:

- it should contain a partition with a FAT32 filesystem
- in that filesystem, there should be a bootloader file located at path `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI`, using the Microsoft PE+ binary format. For other hardware architectures, the filename will be different.
- if Secure Boot is enabled, then the bootloader file must be signed with a Secure Boot certificate that is recognized by the firmware as valid, or the SHA256 hash of the bootloader file must be explicitly whitelisted in the firmware. (There are certain other requirements and restrictions too, and I would urge you to first make your USB work with Secure Boot disabled before trying to make it Secure Boot-compliant.)

At simplest, an UEFI bootloader will be just that: a single `*.efi` file. It might need its own configuration file, or the configuration might be embedded within the bootloader binary.

---

Once you can get the bootloader running, the next steps in booting Linux are specifying *a kernel file* and usually *an initramfs file*. If you can guarantee your Linux root filesystem will be accessible by a filesystem driver built into the kernel, you can technically omit the initramfs file... but usually using an initramfs file will make it much easier to handle different system configurations, which is kind of important if you wish to move the USB from one system to another.

If your goal is just to run one particular Linux utility, you could just package it (and any data files it might need) into the initramfs file, and just configure the initramfs boot process to run it straight from initramfs and never actually mount any other filesystems. Some utilities like disk eraser tool DBAN and old versions of disk tools GParted Live and Clonezilla Live are basically this (modern versions might load an additional squashfs image, if I recall correctly). Some hardware vendors even publish Linux-based firmware upgrade tools packaged in this way.

After a bootloader has managed to load the kernel file and the initramfs file (if used), it will transfer control to the Linux kernel and then the bootloader's job will be done. From that point on, everything is controlled by the Linux kernel and the contents of the initramfs file.